# Error:Could not find facebook-places.jar

Tags: facebook, api

I am using facebook API in my project it was working fine suddenly it is not compiling and showing this error.

Error:Could not find facebook-places.jar (com.facebook.android:facebook-places:4.27.0).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-places/4.27.0/facebook-places-4.27.0.jar

here is my build.gradle line for facebook

compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and i found this solution

just changed

compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'

to

compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'